# Click image to submit the form in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a feedback form with 2 images like this:

```
<form action="/feedback" method="post">
    <div class="col">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Matthewsliquor_CustomerFeedback::images/img-1.png'); ?>" class="img-fluid w-80-px" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Matthewsliquor_CustomerFeedback::images/img-2.png'); ?>" class="img-fluid w-80-px" alt="">
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried to make this 2 images clickable to submit the form and pass value to my controller to get like this:

```
$_POST['value']
```

I tried to change it to input type=image and set value attribute for 2 image but still can not get the value.

Can you give me a solution for this?

THank you very much!

Comment: You can use a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) element to submit the form. Place your `<img>` inside

Comment: and should I set value attribute in button tag or img tag?

Comment: You can add different `name` attributes to the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<button>` elements to submit your form and place your images inside those elements:

```
<form action="/feedback" method="post">
    <div class="col">
        <button name="feedback1">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Matthewsliquor_CustomerFeedback::images/img-1.png'); ?>" class="img-fluid w-80-px" alt="">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <button name="feedback2">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Matthewsliquor_CustomerFeedback::images/img-2.png'); ?>" class="img-fluid w-80-px" alt="">
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In your `/feedback` file you can check which button has submitted the form by checking  `$_POST['feedback1']` or `$_POST['feedback2']`:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['feedback1'])) {
    echo 'button "feedback1" has been clicked';
} elseif (isset($_POST['feedback2'])) {
    echo 'button "feedback2" has been clicked';
}
```